# Linked in OAuth API failing in Android, earlier it used to work fine

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am using OAuth for Linked in Authentication and to bring r_liteprofile.

The code used to work fine for years but now it has stopped working in Android. Strange thing is that it works fine in iOS.

The authentication is successfull but when bringing the profile using https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me for projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams)) and the generate accesstoken, it gives the following error.

{
"serviceErrorCode": 65601,
"message": "The token used in the request has been revoked by the user",
"status": 401
}

I don't understand how a newly created token can be revoked immediately that too in android only?
if verifying the same token on Linked in Developer console using OAuth tools, it says **OAuth token was revoked by the member**

Please Help !

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 0):

I stacked with the same issue on new https://api.linkedin.com/rest/me api endpoint. It looks like linkedin not finish token processing on their side when you come with that token to get profile data. I added 15 sec timeout and all works. Hope they will fix that in future api releases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem getting the user's full name. In my case, scope defined for fetching code was a problem.

Client requested Authorization Code with `r_emailaddress` (which is custom scope for lib we're using in our project). After POST to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${LINKEDIN_REDIRECT_URI}&client_id=${process.env.LINKEDIN_API_KEY}&client_secret=${process.env.LINKEDIN_API_SECRET}` (where `code=${code}` is received Authorization Code) I was able to get email from `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))` by fetching:

```
const emailData = await firstValueFrom(
          this.httpService.get<LinkedInEmailPayload>(
            `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))`,
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
              },
            },
          ),
```

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` was returning the same `"serviceErrorCode": 65601` error code.

To make this work I extended scope defined on the client side to `"r_liteprofile,r_emailaddress"`. After that I was able to successfully call:

```
this.httpService.get<LinkedInUserProfilePayload>(`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
          }),
```

[HERE is the Microsoft documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?view=li-lms-2022-07&tabs=HTTPS)

[Your APP](https://developer.linkedin.com/) in `OAuth 2.0 scopes` section should contains description:

```
r_emailaddress
Use the primary email address associated with your LinkedIn account

r_liteprofile
Use your name and photo
```

Code examples comes from NodeJS app.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023, same issue persists.

Yes, refreshing the access token doesn't make it work immediately, we've put a 10-second timer on making further requests once refreshed.

Comment: Yeah. Even I reported it to Developers still this issue is there